# Compute the most commonly occuring lines in a file using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, file, list, count

I have a PHP script that appends a string to the end of a file. I would like to then be able to read that file and find out the number of times each line occurs, and then compute the most commonly occuring lines and thier numbers. For example, if I have:

```
williamtdr
chicken
chicken
williamtdr
williamtdr
pig
```

I would get:

```
williamtdr, 3
chicken, 2
pig, 1
```

Is there any way to do this in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: `str_word_count()` can be a good start, combined with `array_count_values()` maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//$data = file_get_contents('yourfile.txt'); // get file contents
$data = 'williamtdr
chicken
chicken
williamtdr
williamtdr
pig';

$data = explode("\n", $data); // split data at each newline
$data = array_count_values($data); // count occurrences of each line

print_r($data);
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [williamtdr] => 3
    [chicken] => 2
    [pig] => 1
)
```

**[ [DEMO](http://viper-7.com/VfbWvR) ]**

---

If you want the same output as in your question you would loop over it like so:

```
foreach ($data as $word => $count)
{
    echo $word . ', ' . $count . "\n";
}
```

---

Alternatively, and better is to do it this way:

```
$data = file('yourfile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$data = array_count_values($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you do it in real life?

You would open the file and then start counting:

```
$file   = file('file.txt');
$counts = array();
foreach ($file as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if ( ! isset($counts[$line]) {
        $counts[$line] = 1;
    } else {
        $counts[$line]++;
    }
}
var_dump($counts);
```